# AttributeError when trying to save pandas dataframe to existing excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, attributeerror

I am trying to write a pandas data frame to an existing excel sheet on a new tab, but it gives me the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'.

I've determined this is because pandas to_excel returns a NoneType object, which isn't allowing me to save the file with writer.save(). Does anyone know a workaround for this?

```
path = 'summary.xlsx'
book = load_workbook(path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="results")
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue.
I managed to work around it by removing the value in legacy_drawing from each sheet in the workbook.

```
path = 'summary.xlsx'
book = load_workbook(path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

for s in list(writer.sheets.keys()):
   writer.sheets[s].legacy_drawing = None

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="results")
writer.save()
```